# Invoking the preprocessor from a shell or shell-like program

Tags: shell, command, preprocessor, patch

As mentioned in the title I want to invoke the preprocessor from a shell.

Let me clarify:
  Suppose I have to invoke Preprocessor for command **patch** in Linux say:

```
patch -p1 -D `"{what and how should i write here }"` < patch.patch
```

Patch command has an option `-D` where I can define a preprocessor (to my understanding). I tried searching on Google I got only one [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) I couldn't understand it properly.
Please guide me with an example (or proper reference).

1. What all can be written in -D option of any command?
2. Are constructs same for all command are different for different commands?
3. What can be the input variables?

Answer (score 2):

The `-D` option to `patch` means that the changes made to the patched file will be surrounded by `#ifndef X` / `#else` / `#endif` if `X` is what you specify as the argument to the `-D` option.

For example:

```
$ cat file-1.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
$ cat file-2.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
$ diff -u file-1.c file-2.c > patch
$ patch -DPRINTF_TO_PUTS -i patch --verbose
Hmm...  Looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- file-1.c   2013-02-01 00:33:01.000000000 -0800
|+++ file-2.c   2013-02-01 00:33:17.000000000 -0800
--------------------------
Patching file file-1.c using Plan A...
Hunk #1 succeeded at 2.
done
$ file-1.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
#ifndef PRINTF_TO_PUTS
    printf("Hello world\n");
#else
    puts("Hello world");
#endif
    return 0;
}
$
```

So, to answer your questions:

1. You should put a valid C identifier after `-D` on the `patch` command line.
2. Different commands apply different meanings to any given option letter.  You can find information about common interpretations for options at [The Art of Unix Programming](http://catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s05.html), but there are only 52 alphabetic (single-letter) options and there are many more different meanings for arguments to different commands than that.
3. I'm not sure what you mean by this.

None of this invokes a C preprocessor from the command line.  If you need to do that, look for a program `cpp` on your system.  If you can't find `cpp` anywhere, you may end up invoking `gcc -E` instead.

Comment: What do you mean?  Any other commands that use `-D` as an option?